# Making Python coding locale specific

Tags: python, syntax

I figured out:

- Python is a great programming language.
- Many intelligent kids out there don't know English, but still want to write code.

Does Python support a locale wrapper over its English syntax? Such that all keywords like `import`, `print`, etc. are translated into another human language. Consecutively, translating Python code back-and-forth from one *human* language to another. Reducing English to be just one of several locale-specific human languages. Kids can then write code in *their* language (given their IDE supports [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)), which will boil down to same compiled code.

If not, where do I get started to include this feature in Python through an open source project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Chinese Python](http://reganmian.net/blog/2008/11/21/chinese-python-translating-a-programming-language/) already exists.

A problem with your idea is in libraries – a lot of Python's appeal is in the fact that there's a lot of libraries for it. And virtually all of them use English. Translating all of them is pretty much impossible.

Plus, you don't need much English for Python – it's just individual words like `import`, and `print`. They aren't that hard to learn. After all, kids can easily remember words like `lumos` and `wingardium leviosa`, which aren't in their native language either.

It's much more important to translate manuals and documentation.

Another bad problem with your idea is that if you teach programmers to write in their native language, the rest of the world won't understand them. As for your question, I think the [Chinese Python](http://www.chinesepython.org/) should have some info on how to translate Python. Look at their repository to see the changes.

Comment: My +1 to teach the child the few English words.  It is much more efficient to explain their meaning once or several times.  Also, they will be able to read passively later a lot of the existing code.

Comment: +1 @Petr translating libraries is definitely a problem. But why would it be a problem for the rest of the world? The underlying code will be all in english.. Native language will only be a projection.

Comment: @jerrymouse: See my answer on GvR.  It is written in Python, it uses GUI readable (and enjoyable) in a human language (now ca, cs, de, es, fr, it, nl, no, ro), it combines visual actions with *real programming* in the language.  It is written in Python and the natural later step is to read the Python sources to see how it was implemented.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to make it speaking in your native language, think about using something like [GvR (The Guido van Robot Programming Language)](http://gvr.sourceforge.net/screen_shots/).  You can define the actions using your native language.  There also was some internationalization effort.  For example, it was completely translated into my mother language (including the control commands).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the various modules in the [Python language services](http://docs.python.org/library/language.html) to parse and compile your DSL.